# Misleading text on Help Center page about Close Votes

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, help-center, privileges-page

The Help Center page [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) contains some text which (probably because of changes in the flagging system) is a little bit misleading:

> Note that once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated.

You should *never* flag for moderator attention to have questions closed (the sole exception being a question with an active bounty), and flagging for migration is still a valid option if the target site is not among the predefined migration targets.

Comment: That first quote is probably referring to recommend closure flags. Those are fed to the CV queue and not moderators.

Comment: I think they refer to a time when there were no recommend closure flags, just flags (and moderators/10k users handled all of them). But I wasn't around at that time.

Comment: It seems like this help page was imported from the former privilege wiki.

Comment: It looks like the first line you quoted from that page has been there at least since the oldest revision of that page I can find in the page's revision history (...only visible to CMs, and maybe mods?), which was from October 2013.

Comment: (The phrasing of the second quote has changed slightly since you made this post, so I think that issue may have been fixed...)

Comment: @V2Blast thanks, I agree the second issue was fixed and I've edited it out. We moderators can see the revision history for Help Center articles, but the post IDs are only visible for parts we can edit. We'd need [something else](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1545215/missing-post-ids) to find them for [other articles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/182216/revisions).